# How to rewrite this cURL command to axios code

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

I need to call the propublica API the call example they have is using cURL:

```
  -H "X-API-Key: PROPUBLICA_API_KEY"
```

How can i rewrite it in axios.

I tried this and does not work, get an undefined response.

````
    axios.get('"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/{house}/{FL}/current.json/X-API-Key/APIKEY '),

]).then(axios.spread((response1, response2) => {
    console.log(response1.data.url);

})).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
}); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the RESTClient Extension for firefox, this worked for me:

```
https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/116/senate/members.json
```

with in Header X-API-Key:my-personal -key.
So using axios, you may use:

```
let url = 'https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/116/senate/members.json';
axios.get(url,
  { 
    headers: { 
      'X-API-Key': headerKey 
    }
  }
)
.then (res=>console.log(res))   
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: You are welcome [sairtun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11632596/sairtun). Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

the `-H` option is to pass the option as a header, not as a query parameter or as a part of the URL. You would have to do something like this instead:

```
axios.get(url, { headers: { 'X-API-Key': headerKey } })
```

Comment: I'm trying with this:      ```                const axios = require('axios');

 axios.all([
     axios.get('"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/senate/members.json"',  { headers: { 'X-API-Key': "9q67HMZ2ly0hOrXWjT9l31WN6TiGuh7XrkBl1vC"} })
 ])
     .then(axios.spread((response) => {
     console.log(response.data.url);
 })).catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
 });                        ```            still getting undefined

Comment: What [Mario-F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785/mario-f) and [sairtun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11632596/sairtun) proposed is the right way to do it. Also use headers instead of params.

Answer (score 0):

This is working, thanks for the answers.

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.request({
    url: "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/house/FL/current.json",
    headers: { 'X-API-Key': "API-KEY" },
    method: 'get'
}).then(response => {
    // console.log(response.data.url);
    console.log(response.data)
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```